# How can I limit an annotation 's target only to be 'ElementType.TYPE_USE',

Tags: java, annotations, checkstyle

How can I limit an annotation 's target only to be 'ElementType.TYPE_USE', and any other use would be rejected by 'maven checkstyle' plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only think of [RegexpMultiline](https://checkstyle.org/config_regexp.html#RegexpMultiline), if you want to do it with Checkstyle. You might configure it like so ([regex](https://regex101.com/r/UmOTkP/1)):

```xml
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
  <property name="format" value="\bElementType\s*\.\s*(?!TYPE_USE)\w+\b"/>
  <property name="message" value="Illegal ElementType. Only TYPE_USE is permitted."/>
  <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
</module>
```

This solution is far from perfect, as it will also trigger on comments, and is not limited to annotations. Write a [custom check](https://checkstyle.org/writingchecks.html) if you need more control.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it!

Comment: Yes, it did, Thank you a lot.

Comment: sure！Thank you again!